# How to get started creating Openlayers wrapping API?

Tags: api, maps, openlayers, wrapper, openlayers-3

I am trying to create a wrapper over openlayers-3.

Can anyone provide me with step-wise guidelines to accomplish this?

Comment: it's somewhat too general question. could you try at least one wrapper object for your map service?

Comment: Creating a wrapper for https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch01-getting-started-with-openlayers/example-01.html will do for beginning with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with following code (ES5 style):

```
// wrapper
var myMap = function(target, zoom, center) {
  this.init(target, zoom, center);
};

myMap.prototype = {
  init: function(target, zoom, center) {
    // use actual ol
    return new ol.Map({
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
      target: target,
      view: new ol.View({
        center: center,
        zoom: zoom
      })
    })
  }
};

// call your wrapper method
var map = new myMap("map", 2, [0, 0]);
```

[fiddle](https://codepen.io/cs09g/pen/qpPozp)

Answer (score 0):

Frankly speaking, Openlayers' API is a bit hard to use especially for beginners. I have to use it at work, so I try to write a simple wrapper for easier to use ol.

A simple demo:

```
var proj = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:4490',
    units: 'degrees',
});
var mapOptions = {
    center: [121.84059516385024, 29.902349218390047],
    layers: layerObject,
    zoom: 15,
    projection: proj
};
var map = new OpenMap('mapId',mapOptions);
```

Check it out for more details on Github : [om](https://github.com/lucienlugeek/om)